# Convert an array of objects to a single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, object

**I have an array as:**

```
   [
      {
        path: 'default',
        moduleName: 'asset',
        masterName: 'assetType',
        data: [ { "code":"mov, "name":"Movable"} ]
      },
      {
        path: 'default',
        moduleName: 'common-master',
        masterName: 'city',
        data: [ { "code":"ind.ka.blr, "name":"Bangalore"},
                { "code":"ind.ka.mys, "name":"Mysore"}] ,
        {
        path: "default",
        moduleName: "common-master",
        masterName: "country",
        code:""
         }
       ]
```

**I want to construct an object in javascript:**

```
    Res: {
           Mdms: {
                    default: {
                              asset: { assetType: [ { "code":"mov, "name":"Movable"} ] },
                              common-master: { city: [ { "code":"ind.ka.blr, "name":"Bangalore"},
                                                       {"code":"ind.ka.mys, "name":"Mysore"}],
                                              country: [ {"code": "ind", "name": "India"},                                  
                                                        { "code": "usa", "name": "United States of America"},
                                                         { "code": "aus", "name": "Australia" },
                                                          {"code": "can", "name": "Canada"}]  
                                     }
                           }
                 }
         }
```

I tried reduce method but it is not generating the required output.

```js
ResInfo = finalArray.reduce((ResInfo, arr) => {
  ResInfo[arr.path] = (ResInfo[arr.moduleName] || []).concat(arr);
})
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you show us how you tried to use the reduce method?

Comment: ResInfo = finalArray.reduce( (ResInfo,arr ) => {
            ResInfo[arr.path] = (ResInfo[arr.moduleName] || []).concat(arr);
          })

finalArray is the above array of objects

Comment: can you paste the excepted output

Comment: I have already mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

You should use the reduce function for this, but you need to make a few changes. You can read more about reduce here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```js
// reduce takes as first argument an accumulator (your result) and the current element.
// what you will return will become the new accumulator
finalArray => finalArray.reduce((acc, el) => {
  const path = acc[el.path] || {};
  const moduleName = path[el.moduleName] || {};
  const masterName = moduleName[el.masterName] || [];
  return ({
    ...acc,
    // we merge the path of this object with the accumulator
    [el.path]: {
      ...path,
      // we merge the modulename of this object with the accumulator
      [el.moduleName]: {
        ...moduleName,
        // we merge the data array of this object with the accumulator
        [el.masterName]: [
          ...masterName,
          ...el.data
        ]
      }
    }
  });
}, {});
```

Comment: Hi @tudor.gergely, this works perfectly fine when above array is having two objects. If we add one more object in that array, the solution you gave gives response only for any of the two objects. I have edited the question and mentioned the expected output. What could be done for this now?

Comment: @BikkiMahato you JSON is not correct for the output you want, can you update it?

Comment: @BikkiMahato I updated my answer to fix the issue you mentioned, you can check it again.